# Change user and group for a configmap and secret volume mounts

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

We are mounting all the volumes as a non-root user inside the container in a pod using the securityContext. However, for all the configmaps and secrets the volumemount user is still root. I tried the initContainer approach without any success.

I searched on net and didn't get any information on changing the user for the volumemounts for configmaps/secrets as a non-root user. Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the user in the docker file and uses the below configuration in Kubernetes?

Dockerfile

```
RUN useradd nonroot -u 10001
USER 10001
```

Kubernetes:

```
securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 10001
```

Comment: Yes, the user has been created in the dockerfile. But for secrets and configmaps, it is not effective.